# Where is the amount of Zorkmids I own displayed?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I just started playing Dungeons of Dreadmore. I guess I own some Zorkmids, but I can't find them in the inventory. How do I know how much money I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of money you own is in a separate field on the far left side of the bottom bar, in golden letters.

Answer (score 5):

Your Zorknid total is located on the botton of the screen, at the far left of the item quick access bar, circled on this picture.

[image: Zorknids]